# LINQPad access SqlOutputWriter from custome library

Tags: sql, linq, linqpad

I have written a libraries, that I frequently use with and without LINQPad. The library (DLL) generates SQL and expressions and I would like to write SQL to the SqlOutputWriter of LINQPad, if the library is executed inside a LINQPad-Query.

I have done the following, which worked fine with LINQPad <= 4.51.03 but has stopped working with the latest Betas >= 4.53 where the execution engine of queries has changed.

```
            if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Contains("LINQPad Query Server"))
        {
            var linqPadAssembly =
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SingleOrDefault(ass => ass.GetName().Name == "LINQPad");

            if (linqPadAssembly != null)
            {
                var utilType = linqPadAssembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.FullName == "LINQPad.Util");

                if (utilType != null)
                {
                    var sqlWriterMember =
                        (PropertyInfo)utilType.GetMembers().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "SqlOutputWriter");

                    if (sqlWriterMember != null)
                    {
                        var writer = (TextWriter)sqlWriterMember.GetValue(null, new object[0]);
                        new TextWriterCommandDumper(writer).Dump(cmd);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not load util class!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a correct way of accessing the LINQPad.Utils dynamically?

Comment: Email the author. He's responded to me in the past and his email is on the LinqPad site. If he does respond, it would be good to post his response here also, if he doesn't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think you can fix your current code if you change

```
var utilType = linqPadAssembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.FullName == "LINQPad.Util");
```

to

```
var utilType = linqPadAssembly.GetType("LINQPad.Util");
```

Having said that, the way I prefer to do it is to include a reference to LinqPad.exe in the calling library and wrapper it in such a way that it still runs even if Linqpad is not present at runtime.

This method still works with 4.53.09

Sometimes you want to use a feature that only makes sense if you are actually running under LinqPad (as in your example) and sometimes you want to use a feature of LinqPad if it is available at runtime (even if you are running outside LinqPad)

I've included a sample wrapper showing two examples.

```
public class Wrapper
{

    public static System.IO.TextWriter GetSqlOutputWriter()
    {
        if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Contains("LINQPad Query Server"))
            return InternalClass.GetSqlOutputWriter();
        else return Console.Out;
    }

    public static System.IO.TextWriter GetXhmtlWriter()
    {
        try
        {
            return InternalClass.CreateXHmtlWriter();
        }
        catch (Exception) {}

        return null;
    }


    class InternalClass
    {
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public static System.IO.TextWriter GetSqlOutputWriter()
        {
            return LINQPad.Util.SqlOutputWriter;
        }

        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public static System.IO.TextWriter CreateXHmtlWriter()
        {
            return LINQPad.Util.CreateXhtmlWriter();
        }
    }
```

The first method can be called as in

```
  var writer = Wrapper.GetSqlOutputWriter();

  writer1.WriteLine("Hello");
```

If you are running under LinqPad, it will output to the Sql Output window, otherwise if outputs to the console.

The second method detects if Linqpad is available and can be used like

```
var writer = Wrapper.GetXhmtlWriter();

if (writer != null)
{
    writer.WriteLine( ... );
    var results = writer.ToString();
    ...
}
else
{
     // Linqpad not found.
     ...
}
```

Comment: This illustrates how to deal with the general problem "how can I consume a statically referenced library, but fail gracefully if the library is unavailable?" The answer is to put the methods that rely on that library into a separate class, and load it only when you know the library is available.